# PhonePe integration for recurring payments

Tags: payment-gateway, subscription, phonepe

I'm trying to integrate phone pe's recurring payment / subscription in my website.

Using this document -> https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/system-flow-recurring

For the Mandate Set Up Flow

1. Subscription is created successfully. Steps #1 and #2
2. Submit AUTH Request is also executed successfully. I have used `'paymentInstrument': {"type": "UPI_QR"},` Step #3

In response I get a redirectUrl along the lines of
`ppesim://mandate?pa=` and according to sample response, I should get a different url. Because this link isn't a valid QR

I have tried emailing the support but have received very slow replies and the question still isn't answered.

Comment: Did you get any response for this? I also see that their recurring payment API is quite old and not updated since more than a year

Comment: @KrishnaModi Yes I did get a reply back from their support team. There were 2 issues
1. Some websites that generate QR weren't generating it correctly. 
2. I had to be invited from a firebase invite which gave me access to their UAT simulator using which I can scan it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the documentation at the following link,
https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/submit-auth-request#response-parameters

It mentions, "The WEB redirectType is not supported in v1" and "The web url will not be returned in v1"

You cannot use web as of today for this integration